# How to sum the values of a ko observable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, knockout.js

Updating a really old application. Rails 3.22.xx -> 4.2.xx

This code use to work

```
ko.observable(ko.utils.arrayMap(@posts(), (page) -> page.unread_count()).sum())
```

It would return a number of the total, something like `15`.

After upgrading to Rails 4.2 it returns

```
Uncaught TypeError: ko.utils.arrayMap(...).sum is not a function
```

I'm not sure how to get this so I can just return a sum of that value.  If I remove the sum it returns an array of all the values, which is something like `1,0,0,0,10,0,20`.  It seems I need this value to sum though because it is being called from the view as a method, so If I just add a for loop and add all these up and then assign then to the variable the view still breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about rails, so not sure why it broke while updating... but I do know `sum` is not a default array method in javascript.

I propose you try and replace it with a `reduce`:

```
[1,0,0,0,10,0,20].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) // returns 31
```

You can also skip the `map` operation by summing like so:

```
posts().reduce(
  (total, post) => total + post.unread_count(),
  0
)
```

Comment: I tried this but it keeps throwing an error `SyntaxError: [stdin]:82:101: unexpected ,` and it is because of the `,` after `a + b`

Comment: This works, however I have to remove the `,` as I said above.  With that out the count tracks just fine

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to use knockout utils anymore, all browsers implement Array.prototype.map:

```coffee
ko.observable(@posts().map((page) -> page.unread_count()).reduce((x, y) -> x + y, 0)))
```

or in plain javascript

```js
ko.observable(this.posts().map(function(page) {
  return page.unread_count()
}).reduce(function(x, y) {
  return x + y
}, 0)))
```

Comment: Darn, I was really hoping this would work.  Still returns same error though, `Uncaught TypeError: this.posts(...).map(...).sum is not a function`

Comment: Sorry, `sum` is indeed not a function, you have to use reduce I'll update the response.